# Not delete from database PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-delete

I am trying to delete from my database.

Direct link:

```
 echo "<td>" . "<a href='delete.php?del=$row[id]'>Delete</a>" . "</td>";
```

**delete.php**

```
include("connect.php");

if( isset($_GET['del']))
{
   $id =$_POST['id'];
   $sql = "DELETE termekek WHERE id = $id" ;
   echo "<a href='admin.php'>Back</a>"; 
}
```

But when I click the delete button nothing happens.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: You don't do anything with your SQL query. `$sql` is only a string, it won't manipulate anything that way.

Comment: As @nisbshtr said, you need to _execute_ your query. But before you do, read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html) and fix your SQL syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Direct link, you are missing single inverted quote:

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='delete.php?del=$row[id]'>Delete</a>" . "</td>";
                                            ^ -here
```

It should be like:

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='delete.php?del=$row['id']'>Delete</a>" . "</td>";
```

Also, in your delete.php, you are getting the value via POST, while you are passing id as GET, So make it:

```
// $con or similar is the variable in your connect.php
include("connect.php");

if( isset($_GET['del']))
{
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['del']);    
  $sql = "DELETE FROM `termekek` WHERE id = $id" ;
  echo "<a href='admin.php'>Back</a>"; 
}
```

Now, you need to run the query also.

So this will work:

```
// $con or similar is the variable in your connect.php
include("connect.php");

if( isset($_GET['del']))
{
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['id']);   
  $sql = "DELETE FROM `termekek` WHERE id = $id" ;
  mysqli_query($con, $sql);   
  echo "<a href='admin.php'>Back</a>"; 
}
```

**Also, a small note (sounds obvious):** Do not pass id or sensible data with `GET` method. Anybody can pass the id by merely changing the variable `del` from url to other id and that thing will be bad.

Comment: I've noticed you keep adding to this answer, which is great, but there are still two major problems here - your SQL syntax is incorrect, and you haven't even tried to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @Clive Sorry about that, I didn't noticed that. I have edited the answer with a bit of sql injection prevention and a note.

Answer (score 0):

The basic DELETE command is:

```
DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE {condition_field} = {condition_value}
```

Try to change the your variable to the following content:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM termekek WHERE id = $id" ;
```

If this don't solve your problem, try to catch the errors, using something like:

mysql_error(); (http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-error.php)

PDO:errorInfo(); (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Answer (score -1):

How do you execute your query?

Use :

```
$sql ="DELETE termekek FROM YOURTABLE WHERE id = $id"    
$pdoConnection->prepare($sql);
    $pdoConnection->execute();
```

And avoid using $_GET for important data...

Answer (score -2):

**Direct link:**

```
$id = $row[id];
echo "<td>" . "<a href='delete.php?del=$id'>Delete</a>" . "</td>";
```

And also change:**delete.php**

```
include("connect.php");

if( isset($_GET['del']))
{
   $id =$_GET['del'];
   $sql = "DELETE from termekek WHERE id = $id" ;
   echo "<a href='admin.php'>Back</a>"; 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

```
<?php 
include("connect.php");


    if( isset($_GET['del']) )
    {
$id = (int)$_GET['del'];
        $sql = "DELETE termekek WHERE id = $id" ;
       echo "<a href='admin.php'>Back</a>"; 

    }

?>
```